# How to make «grep -P "foo (b.r)"» display only what's in the brackets? Do I need perl?

Tags: console, grep, regex, perl

I have a large file, and I'm trying to get all matches of a regular expression from it.

`grep -P "foo (b.r)"`

Displays all the lines containing «foo b.r», and I'd like to display only what's inside of the brackets.

Pro question: what to do if I have more than one bracket set? For example «foo (b.r) foo (.ar)», and I want the output to consist only of the thing in the first and the second bracket, separated by a separator.

I'm tagging this Perl, because I'm sure I could use «perl -e "..."» - the question to Perl experts, how to write this? It's been ages since I used Perl :)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps use grep's -o

```
   -o, --only-matching
      Show only the part of a matching line that matches PATTERN.
```

which will leave you with the entire pattern, then follow up with another sed(?) to remove/replace the (foo) delimiters?

I doubt it's 'efficient' but it'll do the job.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ne '/foo \((.+?)\)/ and print "$1\n";'
```

Here `\( \)` are literal parentheses and `( )` create a group.

If a line can match multiple times, this *should* work:

```
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" for /foo \((.+?)\)/g;'
```

---

Decrypting oneliners:

- `a and b` → `if (a) {b}`
- `b if a` → `if (a) {b}`
- `b for a` → `for (a) {b}`